# rake db:create throws "database does not exist" error with postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm using rails 4.1.5 with postgresql 9.1 under Debian 7, and I'm not able to create a database in my development environment. When I run

```
bin/rake db:create
```

I get

```
home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:898:in `rescue in connect': FATAL:  database "direct-dev" does not exist
Run `$ bin/rake db:create db:migrate` to create your database (ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError)
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `connect'
from ...
```

I am trying to create the database so, naturally, it does not exist. However rails should create it ... Here's my config/database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: direct-dev
```

And here's a part of the postgresql log:

```
2014-09-01 19:30:40 CEST LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2014-09-01 19:30:40 CEST LOG:  connection authorized: user=rs database=direct-dev
2014-09-01 19:30:40 CEST FATAL:  database "direct-dev" does not exist
```

Do you have any pointers? I've been at this for more than an hour, and still can't understand why this is happening ...

Thanks!

Comment: what about `username` and `passowrd`?

Comment: I think that is not it: I am using postgresql "peer" authentication method; anyway, just in case, I also added `username` and `password` to database.yml, and still got the same error. I also think that, if it was an authentication problem, postgres would have complained about the user not existing before complaining about the db.

Answer (score 110):

Rails 4.1 [ships with spring preloader](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#spring-application-preloader), and

> New Rails 4.1 applications will ship with "springified" binstubs. This means that bin/rails and bin/rake will automatically take advantage of preloaded spring environments.

which means that the "springified" `bin/rake` will attempt to preload the app, which in turn will attempt to run the initilizers resulting in the problem you're seeing.

To fix / work around this you want to run the initial setup rake tasks without spring. One way to achieve that is to run it with bundler instead:

```
bundle exec rake db:create
```

Comment: You pointed out the problem correctly. If any of the initializers depends on an existing database then the whole rake task `db:create` fails. but what you suggested is not necessarily the generic solution. It might work in your case which is using `spring` but doesn't prevent other initializers

Comment: Works with `Rails 4.2` as well. Thanks!

Comment: If you hit the issue on Rails 4.2 +, this is the correct answer. There is likely no need to mess around in postgres proper.

Comment: Same for Rails 5.0.1. Stopping Spring first or disabling it with DISABLE_SPRING did not change the behavior. Running it without Spring altogether was the only thing that worked.

Answer (score 45):

I found the issue ...

It has to do with Rails initializers: Rails seems to load all the initializers before executing `bin/rake db:create`.

And, in this particular application, there are a few custom initializers which depend on an ActiveRecord model (which, in turn, depends on the database being created, available and with the corresponding table).

Therefore rake never gets to actually execute the task, it fails when executing the initializers. I should have known if I had carefully read the full error message log. This is the full log (see below, in bold, the offending lines):

```
/home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:898:in `rescue in connect': FATAL:  database "ds-dev" does not exist
Run `$ bin/rake db:create db:migrate` to create your database (ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError)
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `connect'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:568:in `initialize'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:435:in `new_connection'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:445:in `checkout_new_connection'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `acquire_connection'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:351:in `block in checkout'
from /home/rs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:350:in `checkout'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
from /home/rs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:541:in `retrieve_connection'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:209:in `table_exists?'
from /home/rs/pr/ds/app/models/property.rb:32:in `get'
from /home/rs/pr/ds/config/initializers/custom/setup_mail.rb:3:in `'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:648:in `block in load_config_initializer'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:647:in `load_config_initializer'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in '
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in '
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /home/rs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
from /home/rs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/rs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:418:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /home/rs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /home/rs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:417:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
from /home/rs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `call'
from /home/rs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /home/rs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/rs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
from /home/rs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
from /home/rs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/rs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
from /home/rs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
from /home/rs/pr/ds/config/environment.rb:5:in `'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:140:in `serve'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:128:in `block in run'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `loop'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `run'
from /home/rs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `'
from /home/rs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/rs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from -e:1:in `'
```

I will work on refactoring the code, in order to get rid of any model dependencies in the initializers (which I'm pretty sure it must be a very bad practice).

Comment: + 1 for stressing the importance of reading error stack traces more closely. Stuff like this is the entire point of having them.

Comment: I had the same problem with the `rack-attack` gem that reads the db in its initialiser. As I don't care about DoS attacks when running rake tasks I wrapped the initialiser in `unless defined?(Rake::Application)`.

Comment: Thank you - same issue for me.

Comment: I had the same problem with the `devise` gem - it requires/reads the DB from the call `devise_for :users (...)` used in the `routes.rb` file. So I had to temporarily comment that call out, then run the `rake` command, then reinstate that call.

Answer (score 16):

You might try running this command-

```
bin/rake db:create RAILS_ENV=development
```

Or this command-

```
bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
```

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue today (in OS X).

**Solved with:**

```
psql -U postgres
CREATE ROLE rolename WITH CREATEDB LOGIN;
```

Use `\du` to check if it's created.

Use `\password rolename` to create a password for that *user/role*.

Then you can setup DB with `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 3):

None of the solutions worked for me, but this worked for me.

```
$ brew services list
$ brew services restart postgresql
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the solutions worked for me, but then I saw that some answers mentioned preloading as part of the problem. I realized I had
`config.eager_load = true` in `config/environments/development.rb`. I changed it to false and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues, as is04 pointed out you probably need at least a `username` value in your database.yml.

You also need to create the postgres role:

```
su - postgres
create role direct-dev with createdb login password 'password1'
```

Comment: I tried, but I think that is not it: the role was already created (as a superadmin, actually), and I am using postgrsql "peer" authentication method. I tried adding only a `username`, and both `username` and `password` to database.yml in any case, and I still got the same error.

Comment: As far as I know migration will automatically create db for SQLite and for Postgres you have to create it on your own on development and further environments.

Comment: That's not correct. Rails defaults to the operating system user that initialized the database as the default `database.yml` template explains: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d7f9adf7941574d0a40a165739938d28f278bd77/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config/databases/postgresql.yml.tt#L28-L32. So `whoami` is used as the default I believe. `psql postgres -U \`whoami\`` should work if the database was initialized with the correct user.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and in my case, I had used `Answer.column_name` in a  validation in the Answer model itself. Because test database was already created on my local so `RAILS_ENV=test rails db:create` was working fine on local, but giving the same error in CI/CD pipeline

It was due to the reason that Rails load all the files inside app/ directory before running `db:create` command, and at that time as no database is there `Answer.column_names` failed.

I used something like this:

```
  validates_uniqueness_of :content, scope: (Answer.column_names - %w[id created_at updated_at]).map(&:to_sym), message: 'Duplicate answer'
```

which is wrong. Then I changed to:

```
DUPLICATE_ANSWER_SCOPE = %i[content question_id session_id]
validates_uniqueness_of :content, scope: DUPLICATE_ANSWER_SCOPE, message: 'Duplicate answer'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue with my setup on a fresh PC and the problem was the user I have had specified in `database.yml` didn't have access to the database, I have raised the access with:

```sql
GRANT pg_read_all_data TO <my_username>;
GRANT pg_write_all_data TO <my_username>;
```

And it started working, the `database.yml` for reference:

```yaml
development:
  <<: *default
  database: <your_db>
  port: 5432
  host: localhost
  username: <your_username>
  password: <your_password>
```

For me the error is kind of throwing off as it says that the DB does not exists but it's in fact permissions issue(or at least it was for me).

Answer (score -1):

Here is my Dockerfile for the rails project.
Take a look at this part:

```
CMD mkdir -p tmp/pids && \
    bundle exec rake db:create && \
    bundle exec rails db:migrate && \
    bundle exec rake db:seed && \
    bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

Bundler 2.1.4, ruby 2.7.2, rails 6.0.3 compatible.
Docker compose part:

```
server:
    container_name: server
    build:
      context: Server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        ENV: 'development'
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - ./Server/.env
    ports:
      - '9090:3000'
    volumes:
      - ./Server:/app
      - ./Server/Docker/usr/.gemrc:/root/.gemrc
    networks:
      - app-network
```

```html
FROM ruby:2.7.2-alpine3.12

# env and arg variables setup
ARG APP_HOME='/app'
ARG ENV
ENV RAILS_ENV=$ENV \
    RACK_ENV=$ENV \
    RAILS_ROOT=$APP_HOME

# timezone setup
RUN apk add --update tzdata && \
    cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London /etc/localtime && \
    echo "Europe/London" > /etc/timezone

# building in tmp dir
WORKDIR /tmp
ADD Gemfile ./

#install dependencies (bundler 2.1.4, ruby 2.7.2, rails 6.0.3 compatible) 
RUN apk add --update --virtual runtime-deps postgresql-client nodejs libffi-dev readline sqlite xz && \
    apk add --virtual build-deps build-base openssl postgresql-dev libc-dev linux-headers libxml2-dev libxslt-dev readline-dev && \
    gem install bundler -v 2.1.4 && \
    bundle install --jobs=4 && \
    apk del build-deps

# /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# create dbs if no such, migrate, seed, start
CMD mkdir -p tmp/pids && \
    bundle exec rake db:create && \
    bundle exec rails db:migrate && \
    bundle exec rake db:seed && \
    bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```